# How to programmatically get a Control's CSS values

Tags: asp.net, css

I am setting styles like so:

```
button2.Style.Add("color", "#eee");
```

How do I now check what the color value of that control is?

`if (button2.Style["color"] == "#eee")` doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at jquery which has a .css method that can both set and query css values.
[Have look at this page](http://api.jquery.com/css/)